# URL Validation function improving

Tags: objective-c, regex, url-validation

i use this function to check if an URL is valid or not. it works for most of the cases, but here the following URL it return that is not Valid!

> http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11841-stringbytrimmingcharactersinset.html

what can i do to improve the regular expression of my function that it will cover all URL types?

```
- (BOOL) urlIsValiad: (NSString *) url 
{
    NSString *regex = 
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

    if ([regextest evaluateWithObject: url] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"URL is valid!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"URL is not valid!");
    }

    return [regextest evaluateWithObject:url];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my attempt:

`((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?`

EDIT
Added in a back-reference `(?<=/)`for extra specificity

EDIT 2
Added optional search for country name in URL (eg www.google.com.in)

Comment: this above pattern is work with http://www.google.com/ but it's not work with http://www.google.co.in/. Please the solution for that. Where can i make changes .. for that. So both format was give validate.

Comment: @MinuMaster Hi, I've changed the search pattern to fix the problem you mentioned. Please see above.

Comment: This reg expression doesn't work for the following link:  http://edition.cnn.com/2012/02/29/world/europe/russia-election-primer/index.html?hpt=hp_c1 how can it be fixed?

Comment: @NavaCarmon Hi Narva, I looks like it's just that that url has a `?` in it. You can add that into the last part of the regex if you like as `\\?`

Comment: Well, I found something on Microsoft site and with slight changes it's the best expression so far - see the answer. It was too long for comment, but it works really well

Comment: @JoshaInglis - ur RegEx helps me a lot, but I want to validate "http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab" kind of url also, could you please he me?? I have tried in current RegEx but it didn't help me, could you please ??

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the *regex = line with following.

**NSString *regex = "(http|ftp|https)://[\w-_]+(.[\w-_]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]*   [\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?"**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found something on Microsoft site and with slight changes it's the best expression so far:

```
@"(?:[A-Za-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"

@"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"

@"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-"

@"z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"

@"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"

@"9][0-9]?|[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"

@"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but I think my amendments may be helpful to someone else landing here:

I didn't like to check only for a "www" as a hostname, nowadays we may encounter different hostnames... Thus I extended the Regex with:

```
"((?:http|https)://)?(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{1,25}\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)validateUrl{
//    NSString *urlRegEx =  @"((?:http|https)://)?(www\\.)[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?";
    NSString *urlRegEx =  @"((?:http|https)://)?(www\\.)[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
    if ([urlTest evaluateWithObject: self] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"URL is valid!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"URL is not valid!");
    }
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:self];
}
```